# Where is the angle for $-{7\pi\over8}$ in a unit circle?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I am having difficulty finding the angle for $-{7\pi\over8}$ in a unit circle. I have found the coordinates for $\frac{\pi}{8}$ and have to use the symmetry to locate the coordinates for $-{7\pi\over8}$. Is the angle just below the $(1,0)$ and symmetry to ${\pi\over8}$? Thank you.

Comment: If the point corresponding to angle $\phi$ is at $(x,y)$, then the point corresponding to angle $\phi\pm\pi$ is at $(-x,-y)$.

Comment: Hint: draw a picture of where the points corresponding to angles $\frac{\pi}{8}$ and $-\frac{7 \pi}{8}$ would be. You'll see that there's an easy way to interpret them.

Comment: Definitely draw a picture! The answer will become clear.

Comment: Also, check out [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). Ideally before asking anything.

Answer (score 2):

$-\frac{7\pi}{8}=\frac{\pi}{8}-\pi$. So you must rotate your point clockwise through an angle $\pi$. This will take you to a point directly opposite the point you started from.

Comment: I am a bit confused now. Where exactly is it in the unit circle and what pi value does it equal to? I need to draw the angle on the unit circle.

Comment: @Max Hong A radian in a circle is the amount of arc ( about $57.3^\circ$) that is equal to the radius. Since circumference = $2\pi$, the same ratio applies in measuring angles. A half circle is $\pi=180^\circ$, $\frac{\pi}{6}=30^\circ$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{-7\pi}8$ is in the third quadrant. So, using $\dfrac {\pi}8$ as your reference angle, make both coordinates negative.

(It is also coterminal with $\dfrac{9\pi}8$, since they differ by $2\pi$.)

Comment: Hi Chris, how did you get 9pi/8? so the angle is just below (-1,0) in the 3rd quadrant?

Comment: That's right.   The _reference angle_ is $\dfrac {\pi}8$.  Remember $2\pi=0$.

Comment: Thank you Chris.

Comment: So, I can write -7pi/8 = 9pi/8 ?

Comment: Yes.  Since $2\pi=0$.  They correspond to the same point on the unit circle.

Comment: Actually, I guess I should be careful and say they are coterminal angles.  They are not actually _equal_.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily turn $-\frac{7\pi}{8}$ into $-(\frac{8\pi}{8}-\frac{\pi}{8})$ which simplified become $-(\pi - \frac{\pi}{8})$. Negative angle mean you're rotating clockwise , so instead of being in 2nd quadrant it's in $2\pi - \pi + \frac{\pi}{8} = \pi + \frac{\pi}{8}$ (in 3rd quadrant).

Answer (score 0):

A full circle is going $2\pi$ radians in the counter-clockwise direction from $(1,0)$. You are going $3$ circles clock-wise plus one more $\pi$ clock-wise so you are at $-180^\circ=180^\circ$. The coordiates are on the x-axis at $(-1,0)$